# Print an integer array pointed at memory

Tags: c, pointers, integer

I encrypt a string by encoding the integer value of each char with a secret.

```
char *buffer; // from file
int *encoded, *decoded;
encoded = encodeMessage(len, 1, buffer, e, n);
decoded = decodeMessage(len, 1, encoded, d, n);
```

The functions returns an integer array pointer

```
int* encodeMessage(...) return encoded;
int* decodeMessage(...) return decoded;
```

So all the data is in memory but now i want to save the en/decrypted messages as ascii strings to files but dont know how to get the messages pointed at with encoded and decoded.

Instead of directly passing the pointer(encoded) to decodeMessage() i want to save it to a file as an ascii string.

Thank you

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you i have edited my question. Instead of directly passing the pointer(encoded) to decodeMessage() i want to save it to a file.

Comment: So `encoded` has a pointer to an array of ints. How large is that array?

Comment: `int len; // length of ints` including the last `\0` of the encoded string

Comment: `len` seems to be the size of the message to encode. Is the encoded message as large as the message to encode?

Comment: Every char in the message became an int so its equal i guess. But as i said the terminating `\0` is included. So `hello` has 5 integer

Comment: `fwrite(encoded, sizeof(int), len, encodedFile);`

Comment: The encoded message will be 4 times the size of the unencoded message. I don't believe that.

Comment: It works, thank you. You should make this an answer.

Comment: You should probably be using a `char` array for the encoded result instead of an `int` array.  Then you won't have the problem you brought up in your other question.